# Fixing Slide Number for Duplicates in LyX

Tags: beamer, lyx, lyx-layouts

I cannot find an answer for this seemingly easy question. In LyX, I build bullet points over several slides, but the slide number continues to increase. Is there a way to designate a set of frames as part of one overarching frame?

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\item Item 3
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

In this MWE I will have 3 slides added to the slide count, but it is the same slide and I am just transitioning in bullets. I do this with graphs too and want to nest frames as one slide count (i.e., the above would add one slide to the total).

Comment: Are you using the `[allowframebreaks]` option? A screenshot illustrating the problem would probably help here.

Comment: @KevinC Added in a MWE, sorry for being lazy

Comment: Have you looked at the beamer examples? Go to File > Open, then click on "Examples" (I know this button exists on Ubuntu, I forget what to do for Macs). Then open the files that say "beamer". In LyX 2.1 you will be able to go to Help > Specific Manuals > Beamer Presentations. You should see examples that do what you want

Comment: Looks like you can just use the overlay specifications of Beamer instead of creating a new frame each time you introduce a new item. For instance `\begin{frame}\begin{itemize}\item<1-> Item 1 \item<2-> Item 2 \item<3-> Item 3 \end{itemize}\end{frame}`. This would introduce items one by one while the page count stays the same

Comment: @KevinC This does work for items but how about graphs that are not itemized or if I want to bring in Item 1-3 in one slides and Items 1-5 on another? Also, how is this done in LyX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ERT box (`Insert`->`TeX code`, or simply click the TeX button) to pass overlay specifications. In fact, the ERT box allows you to enter any TeX/LaTeX codes you'd like.

### Step 1. Enter frame contents

[image]

### Step 2. Add overlay specifications

- First bring cursor to the beginning of an item
- Open an ERT box by clicking the TeX box (or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> in Windows)

[image]

- In the ERT box enter the overlay specifications (do this for all items)
- For texts/graphs not in an `itemize` environment, use the ERT box to enter overlay commands like `\only`, `\visible`, `\onslide`, or `\alt`

[image]

### Output

[image]

Once you're more familiar with how this works, you can just use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to enter overlay specifications as you type out the contents without having to follow the above steps rigidly.

Comment: This is not working, does any special package need to be loaded?

Comment: SKevinC Windows

Comment: @CJ12: See updated answer

Comment: @CJ12: BTW, don't forget about insert an EndFrame at the end of the document.

Comment: +1 Nice answer Kevin. Note that the "pause" layout might also be useful here.

Comment: And (just in case you're curious) I don't think we'll need many "EndFrames" in the new beamer support in LyX 2.1 (although you will need "separators" but this is nicer)

Comment: @scottkosty: thanks! ah I forgot about `\pause`. I thought there still has to be at least one EndFrame at the end of the document, or is that no longer needed?

Comment: (I forgot to actually give the +1. oops. Just fixed that). I might be mistaken but I don't think you need an EndFrame at the end of the document anymore. In fact, I don't even know if "EndFrame" exists in LyX 2.1. I haven't played around enough with it though. If you happen to be using Ubuntu, it's easy to check out (without uninstalling your current version of LyX).

Comment: @KevinC This is great any idea why when I apply this to a sentence with parentheses that they are always visible even if they are included in the braces? Also, it is not applying to formatted text for example I have a few words centered at the bottom of the slide in italics and nothing changes when the ERT is added.

Comment: @ChrisJ: Hmm.. Having formatted texts or parentheses shouldn't affect the overlay commands. Are you sure that the braces used in the overlay command are put in an ERT box? One way to check whether you're using the overlay commands correctly is to see it in the source code: in the menu bar, select `View`->`View Source` and see if the code has something like `\visible<3>{\textit{italic text} with (parentheses)}`.

Comment: @KevinC Fixed it, you cannot add them ex post to formatted sentences or it messes up the code. That was the issue